# Three.js Rotate objects inside of moving Object3D to always face the camera

Tags: matrix, camera, rotation, three.js

I'm somewhat new to Threejs was just wondering how to make moving mesh always face the camera in a scene. I have 100 meshes inside of a container Object3D, and am rotating this container on the x and y axis. Is there any way to force the meshes inside of the container to always face the camera?

Here is some sample code, I've also set up a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/nickelWeb/rZtJX/4/

```
for(var k = 0; k<numMeshes; k++){
     meshes[k].lookAt( camera.position );   
}
```

I have tried just using the .lookAt() method but it doesn't seem to be working. I know there has to a way to do this i'm just not sure where to look. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.lookAt()` will not work correctly if the object has a parent that is rotated.

The absolute easiest solution to your problem is to hold the parent object fixed and rotate the camera around the object instead.

That way, `Object.lookAt()` will work as expected.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rZtJX/5/

three.js r.57

Comment: Is there any way I could do it without moving the camera? Like some sort of globalToLocal conversion?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but the sense of "up-ness" would be changed. So the objects would look at the camera, but would not be right-side-up. You can try `THREE.SceneUtils.detach()`, followed by `lookAt()`, and then `THREE.SceneUtils.attach()` for each object, but that is terribly inefficient, and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Okay Thanks! I will try your first suggestion.

Comment: I think @WestLangley 's solution (detach, lookAt, attach) is actually a pretty good solution, especially if you don't have to do it in every render/update cycle. One thing to keep in mind: you have to update the object's matrix before the attach, something like this:
1) detach
2) lookAt
3) updateMatrix
4) attach

Comment: @ViktorBenei Correct. three.js r.61