# THREE js rotationon one axes toward camera, not affected by parent

Tags: three.js

I have situaton:

```
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);
        scene.add(camera);

    var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
        parent.position.set(1,2,3);
        scene.add(parent);

    var child = new THREE.Object3D();
        child.position.set(4,5,6);
        parent.add(child);


   var v = new THREE.Vector3().copy(child.position); 
       child.localToWorld(v);

   child.rotation.z = Math.atan2( ( v.x - camera.position.x   ), ( v.y - camera.position.y ) );
```

It works and child is facing camera on Z axis.

When i do:

```
parent.rotation.set(1,2,3); // or whatever
```

child is affected by rotation, how to avoid that rotation and keep the child in same rotation like before the parent was rotated (update local rotation to be the visually unchanged by parent transformation), but to keep a global position changed due parent rotation?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734049/invert-rotation-of-parent-in-the-child-so-the-child-appears-unrotated-in-the-wo

Comment: Thank you, and what to do if parent is rotated?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following after you have set the rotation of your child object:

```
var matrix = new Matrix4();
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

parent.updateMatrixWorld(); // ensure matrixWorld is up to date
matrix.extractRotation( parent.matrixWorld );
quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix( matrix );
child.quaternion.premultiply( quaternion.inverse() );
```

Comment: hi thanks, I'm calling update of rotation in each frame. It seems that this is not calculate final angle but it adds angle to existing. In the result it causes that child object is rotating around Z axis (Only if parent rotation is not 0,0,0)

Comment: Can you please demonstrate your current code as a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? The code from my post is essentially a snippet from `Object3D.lookAt()` which supports rotated parents.