# how to rotate dummy object and make child looks always towards camera?

Tags: rotation, three.js

How to rotate dummy object with `three.js` and make child  looks always towards camera? seems that when  the dummy(`3Dobject`)rotates `objectchild.lookAt`(`camera.position`) stops working, can this be solve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734049

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603111/

Comment: hi @gaitat I tried the first approach, it seems to work but when you move the camera the illusion is lost :(