# Three.js Scene utils detach / attach for character weapons

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to build a FPS with Three.js, and I can't get past some major glitches I'm experiencing with `THREE.SceneUtils.detach()` and `THREE.SceneUtils.attach()` (honestly I'm not even sure I should be using them)

My mech character has 2 guns on either side, and there is enough space between the two that a small enemy could fit between the two guns and never get shot. The only solution I could think of was to have the guns "lock on" and follow an enemy when they enter the center of the camera. This solved my issue where an enemy could slip between the guns, but in order to pull this off I followed  WestLangley's idea found here: [Three.js Rotate objects inside of moving Object3D to always face the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603111/three-js-rotate-objects-inside-of-moving-object3d-to-always-face-the-camera#comment22130445_15603613)

So now, my (paraphrased) code looks like this:

```
autoTarget: function ( target ) {

    THREE.SceneUtils.detach( gunRootObject, characterRootObj, scene );
    gunRootObject.lookAt( target );
    gunRootObject.updateMatrix();


    this.direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
    this.direction.applyQuaternion( gunRootObject.quaternion );
    THREE.SceneUtils.attach( gunRootObject, scene, characterRootObj);
}
```

This works about 50% of the time. The other 50% both guns end up stuck at [0,0,0] relative to the `characterRootObj`

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Am I even using the right approach to solve my original issue?

I would greatly appreciate any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Did this work for you at all?

Comment: @zehelvion I ended up scrapping the entire system. What I ended up doing was faking a huge amount of the behaviour - with far more enjoyable results. It came down to greatly simplifying my code, while trying to render a visually satisfying experience that didn't feel like a "cheat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, I took en entirely different approach: I realized I don't need the `lookAt()` function when all I need is to rotate one fixed object relative to a moving one. So, now I'm using basic trig functions to calculate the angle I need to rotate my guns based on the distance of the enemy from the camera & a couple other fixed points.

Since the guns are in a fixed position relative to the camera, I think this will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with that method, it seems that the function scrambles the position of the children, so you cant for loop it reliantly, what worked for me was

```
    while (this.scalerSphere.children.length) {
        THREE.SceneUtils.detach(this.scalerSphere.children[0], this.scalerSphere, scene)
        this.scalerSphere.updateMatrixWorld()
    }
```